# working with CardLayout and FormPanels

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to implement a wizard and I am using the `CardLayout`. The wizard has 3 screens with some form elements. So, basically I need to have a form that is split into 3 screens and user moves from one screen to next only if the data entered is valid.

The trouble is, How do I represent the form? I will need all the data to be submit when the user finally completes the wizard. I tried these two methods:

1. **Use card layout on a form panel.** In this case, the form elements are not rendered properly.
2. **Use form panel for each screen in card layout panel.** In this can the forms get rendered and the UI functionality is good. But how do I send the data spread over three forms to one post method?

So, what do I do? Ideas and suggestions please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option number 1 is the best solution, in fact I wouldn't even consider number 2 because it's not very scalable.

I am assuming that by "the form elements are not rendered properly" you are missing your form layout in each card.

```
items: [{
    id: 'card-0',
    layout: 'form',
    items: [{
        //items here
    }]
},{
    //other cards
}]
```

Comment: Ah! yes :) .. that is what I was missing! didn't have the layout: 'form' in each cards.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Considering the option with a Ext.form.FormPanel in each item of the CardLayout you could prevent submitting each of those forms and in the last one attach a listener to the "submit" button that loops over the items in your CardLayout panel and gets all form values by calling the getFieldValues() method of BasicForm on each.

```
var formValues = {};

CardLayoutPanel.items.each(function(panel){
    if (panel.isXType('form')) {
        Ext.apply(formValues, panel.getForm().getFieldValues());
    }
});

// Now you can dispatch an ajax request with Ext.Ajax that sends the
// formValues variable as parameters to your backend to process
// all values from the three forms.
```

Comment: I did think about this.. but its a lengthy process compared to using a single FormPanel..